# postfix wont receive emails from external network

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix

I have postfix running on one of my Debian servers. I can send and receive emails anywhere from within my network and I can send emails out to an external network, but I can not receive any from my yahoo account. Below are some troubleshooting steps I have tried.

1. I called my ISP and told them to unblock port 25
2. When I used open port checker it says port 25 is open.
3. I can telnet into it using port 25.
4. When I send an email to the server from my yahoo account the mailer-daemon does not even give me a failure notice.
5. I have both UDP and TCP data on port 25 forwarded to the server.
6. The host name that I have registered to my public IP is resolving correctly.
7. Emailing using the public IP instead does not make a difference.
8. I have a Linux Academy subscription, which gives me access to 6 lab servers. I created a new Debian 7 lab server and all I used was:

   $ sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils

   and it was able to recieve emails from an external network. So I'm     pretty sure my configuration is ok.
9. My Debian server has no firewall.

I'm out of ideas any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, it was actually a bad postfix destination.